# How to use regular expression to detect parenthesis at the end of a string?

Tags: python, regex

I am using `if`/`elif` statements in Python to match some strings, but I need help in matching one particular type of string. I want all strings that have parenthesis `'()'` in the end to match the same `if` condition. For example, `string = "Tennis (5.5)"` or `string = "Football (6.3)"`.

```
def method(string):
    if (string has parenthesis in the end):
```

Can I use some regular expression for this ? I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: `')$'`? But why a regular expression, not `.endswith(')')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this,

```
if re.search(r'(?m)\([^()]*\)$', line):
```

`$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question. If I have few strings that have the same name but different values in parenthesis. For example: string="points (0.4)" or "points (0.12)". How can I write a regular expression to match such strings ? thanks

Comment: try `^points \(\d+\.\d+\)$` for both integer as well as floating point numbers, it would be `^points \(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)$`

Answer (score 0):

In the case you'd prefer regex, this is probably the simplest solution. It asserts, if there is a closing parenthesis at the end of line, irrespectively of trailing blanks:

> "\)$"

For example:

```
test1 = "Tennis (5.5) "
test2 = "Football (6.3)"

res1 = bool(re.search(r"\)$", test1.strip()))
res2 = bool(re.search(r"\)$", test2.strip()))

print(res1, res2, sep='\n')

>>> True
>>> True
```